# URL slideshow add-on/plugin/application with timer AND auto refresh

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, plugins, add-on

I am looking for a plugin/add-on for any web browser which lets me start a slideshow of various websites. E.g. show http://page1.com for 10 seconds, then show http://page2.com for 10 seconds, then page1.com again and so on and so on, in a loop.

I've found plugins doing just this, "Tab slideshow" for Firefox and another similar for Chrome.

However, the page needs to refresh when it is to be shown again.

Is there a plugin/add-on or why not a standalone application for Windows that can do this?

Thanks in advance,

- W

Answer (score 0):

There's an extension to Firefox called Flem that does this pretty well. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flem/

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported anylonger in the latest firefox versions but I found a similar one for chrome called URL Loader: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-loader/pehlobngallbbadijocicdimmcpcckhl/related